# Java: need to remove the blanks at the beginning of each line and replace them with an integer count of the number of blanks present (for each line)

Tags: java, compression, java.util.scanner

This is the code i have so far...What should be printed: Two spaces should follow after the integer value, then the rest of the line should be transferred unchanged. And if theres a blank line then don't print it. lets just say the file i'm reading from is a txt file of the code I posted down below. Any help is great, thanks! :)

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class squeeze
    {
        public static void main(String args[]) {

            readWriteFile();

        }

        public static void readWriteFile(){

            try {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("practice.txt")); 
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("DATAOUT.TXT"));
           String line;


        while (scan.hasNext()){ 

            line = scan.nextLine(); 
           if(line.length() == 0){
            scan.nextLine();
        }
            System.out.println(line.trim());
            out.write(line);


        }
        out.close();
        scan.close(); 

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File error" + e);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you practice contains and what the output should look like ?

Comment: Sorry im not so fluent with using this site. There is an example of input/ output at http://www.missblomeyer.com/docs/broadway/Lab%20Assignment%20A13.3%20-%20Squeeze.pdf

Comment: I think someone answered your question but you should really try to make more attempts on your own and try debugging your code since this is an homework problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count the spaces, and replace them:

```
int spaces = 0;
while (spaces < line.length() && line.charAt(spaces) == ' ')
    spaces++;

if (spaces < line.length()) {
    out.write(spaces + line.substring(spaces) + System.lineSeparator());
}
```

Running that on itself would produce:

```
0int spaces = 0;
0while (spaces < line.length() && line.charAt(spaces) == ' ')
4spaces++;
0if (spaces < line.length()) {
4out.write(spaces + line.substring(spaces) + System.lineSeparator());
0}
```

Hope none of your lines start with a number, otherwise you won't know where the spacecount ends and the line text starts.

Comment: Thank you so much! The answer was perfect!